# How to display bold text in only parts of JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Can I alter the text of a `JTextArea` to bold (append text) and then back to normal and will it only display the bold text in bold and the rest as normal?

Also can the contents of `JTextArea` be saved as an RTF document?

Comment: I would use a JTextPane. It is easier to work with than trying to format and manipulate HTML. Click on the link to the Swing tutorial for a working example.

Comment: thanks. please contribute the link. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. What you're looking for is [JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)

This supports HTML (3.2?) which will allow you to use `<font>` (and other older tags) to provide rich text.

```
JEditorPane textarea = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
textarea.setText("Here is some <b>bold text</b>");
```

**EDIT**: According to the javadoc I referenced above, JEditorPane also supports limited RTF. Don't forget to change the MIME to `text/rtf`

Comment: how would you go about appending text to JEditorPane? setText? getText?

Comment: @ikurtz Yep, `setText(getText() + "...");`

Comment: sorry but this does not work. as multiple <html></html> tags are introduced so only the first occurance is displayed and rest of the data ignored.

Answer (score 3):

```
 textArea.setFont(textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, textArea.getFont().getSize()));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a [JTextPane or JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for that.