# How to stylize (make bold) text in a JTextArea?

Tags: javascript, swing, jtextarea

```
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Employee Information");
    sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("Name:");
    txt.setText(sb.toString());
```

Here I need to set **"Employee Information"** to BOLD format..How to do that..
I tried like this

```
 sb.append("<html><b>Employee Information</b></html>");
```

But its printing the text normally... how to make bold?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713863/java-jtextarea-bold

Comment: I tried..                                                                  JEditorPane textarea = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
textarea.setText("Here is some <b>bold text</b>"); sb.append("<b>Employee Information</b>");
    sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("Name:");
textArea.setText(sb.toString());                                         But its not coming..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display bold text in only parts of JTextArea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713863/how-to-display-bold-text-in-only-parts-of-jtextarea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JText Area is a plain text area, for styled text areas you need something like [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) or JTextPane, take a look at the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `setFont` method. For your example try :

```
Font font = txt.getFont();  
txt.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
```

(Keep in mind that `txt` is the `JTextArea`, not your actual text.)