# JTextArea JLabel compare two txt. files line by line

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea, compareto

everybody. I have completed my code two txt files by showing on the same area.

but I want to compare two txt files line by line. and I want to show the differences with Colored lines and finally, The letter or words that are different, different line I'm going to bold.

how can i start?

thanks for now, my code is here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713863/how-to-display-bold-text-in-only-parts-of-jtextarea) - which has a solution recommending using [JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html), rather than `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 2):

`JTextArea` might make a suitable view, but you still need to model the differences. I'd look at the [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/platform/) or [NetBeans](http://platform.netbeans.org/screenshots.html) platforms, or perhaps [`svnview`](http://code.google.com/p/svnview/).

Comment: any advice for the algorithm?

Comment: See also [`diff`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm). In all sincerety, is there a compelling reason to re-invent this?

Comment: just because I don't find a simple diff algorithm on the ınternet, I have confused, so I have to do this.

Comment: `JTextArea` is only plain text, wouldn't you need a `JTextPane` in order to provide attribute support for coloring?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Good point, also raised by Rob, above. `JTextArea` is a little more nimble, and it supports highlighting; it _might_ be suitable. vstl: AFAIK, there is no easy answer. What have you tried? [`diff-utils`](http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/)?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to ask user to upload both versions of file.

In the server you need to compare line by line, and store the line numbers of the file differences in another file or location

Then, while displaying, get the line numbers and give them proper decoration (i.e bold etc.).