# different "words" in two text files and make bold them, show on the screen in two txt. files

Tags: java, string, swing, project

I have compared two text files and found different words each other. And I want to show the different words in two text files and make them bold, show on the screen.

This is my code for comparing but I didnt do that how can i show the different words in these txt. files visually.

Comment: You'll need some GUI that is capable to display text in different styles, like Swing or SWT. The basic building bricks are a window (frame) and two (rich-)text fields to display both texts.

Comment: I used GUI frame to show these text files on the screen.apart from this, I compared these files, found different words. but how can I show these different words in two txt. files on the screen?

Comment: how can I find these different words in my two txt files? also I want to make them seem to be bold.

Comment: some text fields accept HTML as input. Simply wrap the "different" words in `<b>...</b>`. Finding the differences and their *locations* is a job for your comparator.

Comment: @Andreas_D how can i use comparator, between in txt.file which have different words and for example the first txt. file

Comment: This is your ninth question on this topic, posting as [Jes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1573438/jes) and [vstl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1559593/vstl). The problem is not simple. There are no simple examples. Nobody is going to write this code for you.

Comment: @trashgod if you look at my code again, you will really understand, it is not the same according to my other questions! I struggle a lot to find a better solution !!!

Comment: if you say that this question is still same as others, you had better give some advice, ok!

Comment: You have my previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11727609/230513). You have the obligation to cite previous attempts to help you.

Comment: @trashgod can you have an idea, how can I read deneme3.txt file which have different words between two txt files, I want to read this file instead of taking the word from user. can you have a look at my code for the deneme3.txt

Answer (score 1):

When you have a word list, you need to create two `JTextPane`s, put the text documents in them and highlight the differences.

Code examples: [JTextPane Highlight Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneHighlightExample.htm) and [Inserting Styled Text in a JTextPane Component](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/tp_StyledText.html)

Comment: the first example for the highlight is really diffucult to solve my problem can you give me a simple example as a link??

Comment: No, you will actually have to sit down and spend some time thinking about the problem :-)

Comment: thank you for your advice, but can you join me when I was spending my time with thinking? :)

Comment: Sure. Post more questions when you get stuck but please try to achieve something yourself. This isn't a magic "write my code for me" site; we try to help people like you understand what you need to do. In this case, you should compile the example for java2s and run it (maybe in a debugger) to understand how it works.

Comment: I have txt. file which have different words, but I don't know how can I show them in any txt files, and  finally on the screen.

Comment: I dont say that you should give me the code, I only ask you for advice, you can say some ways to solve my problem. cause I have confused

Comment: Did you run the "JTextPane Highlight Example"?

Comment: yes but I had an error at this line:        System.out.println("Failed to load file " + args[0]);

Comment: Hint: Maybe the code has a bug? Which file is it trying to load?

Comment: ok the code compiles. but I want to ask a question. I dont want to enter a word, instead of this, I want my txt file which have different words pair off another txt file's words, seem to make the words bold or underlined. how can i do that?

Comment: Hint: How does the example know which word to highlight? How could you feed your word list into `WordSearcher`?

Comment: This is your ninth question on this topic, posting as [Jes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1573438/jes) and [vstl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1559593/vstl). The problem is not simple. There are no simple examples. Nobody is going to write this code for you.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla firsly, thank you for your example, on the link. it really helps to me. I adapt my solution of my question. I edit my code again according to your link.can you have a look at again? I'm stick:S  still, my txt. file which have different words can not be bold in any txt file.

Comment: I cant not match deneme3.txt which have different words between other txt files to seem to make the words bold

Comment: I think instead of the word can be my deneme3.txt. when the contents of my deneme3.txt matched other files' contents, then, the words can be bold.?  @AaronDigulla ?

Comment: Hint: Maybe you can return a list of word to highlight from `compare()`?

Comment: where can I return a list of word? in main or compare method? or String [] wordList= word; ? in  actionPerformed method?

Comment: @AaronDigulla how can I take the words from txt file and like this example make underlined it. I dont want to take the words from the user

Comment: @Jes: You must return the list of words from `compare()` since this is where the list is created. Alternatively, you could open the third file and read the words from there but this will be much slower.

Comment: I compared two text files by using ArrayString and write the different words another txt file. I want to read this file and if the words matches other txt files,make them underlined. BUt I cant read txt file, instead of "word"

Comment: @AaronDigulla how can I read the deneme3.txt instead of taking the word from user? above there, in my code, you can see deneme3.txt file

Comment: Jes: I'm sorry, if you don't understand such a simple and basic concept, then there is no way for me to help you. Try to find an introductory level programming course in your neighborhood.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I think it isnt possible what I want to you, okey then

Comment: @Jes: Impossible? It would lake me about 3 minutes to do it :-) So I really can't see where your problem is.

Comment: how can you do that then ? before saying I'm sorry,, can you read one more time my question about deneme3.txt :)

Comment: how can I read the deneme3.txt instead of taking the word from?user? all i want to do is :)