# How to set a part of the text in a text area bold?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextarea

[I want to display the values in bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M11y0.png)

I need to change the values to bold not the whole text.

Here is my code:

```
public String displayOrder(){
    String order = "Order " + count + 
            "\nLength of pipe: " + decimal2.format(length / 39.37) + 
            "m" + "\nDiameter of pipe: " + decimal2.format(outerDiameter) + 
            "''" + "\nGrade of pipe: " + grade +
            "\nColour of pipe: " + colour +
            "\nInner insulation: " + convertToStr(innerInsulation) +
            "\nOuter reinforcement: " + convertToStr(outerReinforcement) +
            "\nChemical resistance: " + convertToStr(chemicalResistance) +
            "\nNumber of pipes: " + quantityOfPipes;
    return order;
}
```

Comment: Thats just a string returning method. What's your code attempt to set them bold? And `JTextArea` is not what you should be using. It can't do what you want. Try `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` instead.

Comment: `JTextArea` doesn't support formatting, instead you need to use either a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane`, see [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for more details

Comment: You might also consider using a `JTable`

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with a [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) using html tags:

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
editorPane.setText("Test <b>bold</b>");
```

You can't do that with a JTextArea, the closer you can get is to change the font:

```
textArea.setFont(textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
```

The problem is this changes the font for the entire text.

Comment: That's a bit complicated and I don't have much time I submit tomorrow, anyway thanks for the help mate:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with a regular jtextarea, you should try a 
JEditorPane

```
JEditorPane textarea = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
textarea.setText("Here is some <b>bold text</b>");
```

[How to display bold text in only parts of JTextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713863/how-to-display-bold-text-in-only-parts-of-jtextarea)

Comment: If you're going to link to a duplicate question to answer this question, which provides no new information, then you should either use a comment or vote to close this question as a duplicate, right now, you're hoping to gain reputation for some one else's hardwork. Don't get me wrong, if you used a previous answer as bases of your answer and improved upon it, then quoting the original is a good idea

Comment: Look buddy I submit my coursework tomorrow and I thought of something extra to add to my program, I don't really have time to look if somebody else asked the same question.. :)

Comment: Hugo Rocha thanks for the help mate :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hey, I honestly didn't know what was the protocol so I just answered it. I didn't want to copy the other question that's why I quoted it. Anyhow I'm sorry next time I will take that in mind. Thanks.